# Is "deck" always on the back of a house?

Tags: word-meaning

Is "deck" always on the back of a house? I know that a porch is always in the front. Thanks!

Comment: “A porch is always in the front” is completely wrong.

Answer (score 3):

A deck can be just about anywhere on a house. In fact, I have one on the side of my house build on a flat roof above an extension of the house. And, my next door neighbor has one on the front of his house just beside his porch.

The keys are that a deck is (1) attached to the building and (2) does not have a roof.

Merriam Webster defines them as mentioned below:

> A [deck](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deck) is *a flat roofless structure attached to a building.*

On the other hand,

> A [porch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/porch) is *a structure attached to the entrance of a building that has a roof and that may or may not have walls.*

I, however, would refer to any raised area immediately adjacent a main entrance to a house as a porch, whether or not it has a roof.

Another example of a deck is a rooftop deck that is commonly found on top of condominium apartments.

Also, the area around a pool (both in-ground and above-ground kinds) is called a deck, but this may be getting into [other definitions](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/DECK) of the word, such as the floors on a ship.

Comment: Is this something specific to American English? As a British English speaker, I associate decks with ships, not houses. The equivalent BrE term may be "decking" - and I see that searching for the latter on Wikipedia takes you to the article for "deck" [(link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decking).

Comment: Steve: You may well be right.  In the USA, I believe that [decking](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decking) refers to the materials used to make what we call a deck. A quick search of US DIY websites is consistent: [Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Lumber-Composites-Decking/N-5yc1vZbqmg) and [Lowes](http://www.lowes.com/Building-Supplies/Decking/_/N-1z11px3/pl).  You would buy decking to build your deck.